# Closed form of sum of weighted roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I came out with the following sum $S_n$ (for positive integer $n>1$):

> $S_n = \sum _{k=1}^{n-1} k e^{\frac{2 \pi k i}{n}} = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{n}}
> + 2e^{\frac{4 \pi i}{n}} + 3e^{\frac{6 \pi i}{n}}  + \cdots + (n-1)e^{\frac{(2n-2) \pi i}{n}} \qquad n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

which consists of roots of unity $e^{\frac{2\pi k i}{n}}$, but with some **weights**(k). Though for the sum of roots of unity $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{\frac{2 \pi k i}{n}} = 0$, this result does not seem to help me to get $S_n$.

Is there any way to get $S_n$ in closed form?

Thank you.

Comment: Your last term is missing its coefficient, $n-1$. But anyway you can find a general formula for $\sum kx^k$, and then let $x=e^{2\pi i/n}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah, that gives the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> S_n(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kx^k=x\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kx^{k-1}
> =x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x^k\right)\\
> &=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}-1\right)\\
> &=\frac{(n-1)x^{n+1}-nx^n+x}{(1-x)^2}
> \end{align*}
>
> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{S_n\left(\exp(2\pi i/n\right))}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\exp\left(2\pi i/n)\right)\\
> &=\left.\frac{(n-1)x^{n+1}-nx^n+x}{(1-x)^2}\right|_{x=\exp(2\pi i/n)}\\
> &=\frac{(n-1)\exp(2\pi i/n)-n+\exp(2\pi i/n)}{\left(1-\exp(2\pi i/n)\right)^2}\\
> &=\frac{n(\exp(2\pi i/n)-1)}{\left(1-\exp(2\pi i/n)\right)^2}\\
> &=\color{blue}{\frac{n}{\exp(2\pi i/n)-1}}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Indeed, $S_n(x)$ gives the closed form. Thank you!

Comment: @Matholic: You're welcome! :-)